# python SQLite 3 formatting proper request

Tags: python, sqlite

Hi I don't understand why

```
    sql = '''SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name =':name' and type='table' '''
    cursor.execute(sql,{'name' : table_name})
```

Don't work(Return None) but

```
    sql = "SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name ='" + table_name + "' and type='table'"
    cursor.execute(sql)
```

This one work...
I really want to use the first one since it's a way better and proper but I don't understand why is not working.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the reasons for using parameter substitution in SQL queries is that it takes care of quoting for you. So by putting in the quotes yourself in that first snippet, you end up with double quotes, which won't match. The query should just be:

```
sql = '''SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name =:name and type='table' '''
```

Comment: Thanks for the explaination ! it's working fine now :)

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you.